# in Java, can I keep tracking all the value in a switch statement for each case?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I am just starting the learn Java, I need to use a switch statement, but I need to keep track of all the value of calculation for each case and then need to add it up. how can I do it?

and here is my code for now

```
            switch(productNo)
            {
                case 1:
                    lineAmount1 = quantity * product1;
                    orderAmount = +lineAmount1;
                    textArea.append(productNo +"\t"
                            + quantity + "\t" 
                            + "$" + lineAmount1 +"\t"
                            + "$" + orderAmount + "\n" );


                    break;
                case 2:
                    lineAmount2 = quantity * product2;
                    orderAmount = + lineAmount2;
                    textArea.append(productNo +"\t"
                            + quantity + "\t" 
                            + "$" + lineAmount2 +"\t"
                            + "$" + orderAmount + "\n" );


                    break;

                case 3:
                    lineAmount3 = quantity * product3;
                    orderAmount = +lineAmount3;
                    textArea.append(productNo +"\t"
                            + quantity + "\t" 
                            + "$" + lineAmount3 +"\t"
                            + "$" + orderAmount + "\n" );

                    break;

                case 4:
                    lineAmount4 = quantity * product4;
                    orderAmount = +lineAmount4;
                    textArea.append(productNo +"\t"
                            + quantity + "\t" 
                            + "$" + lineAmount4 +"\t"
                            + "$" + orderAmount + "\n" );

                    break;

                case 5:
                    lineAmount5 = quantity * product5;
                    orderAmount = +lineAmount5;
                    textArea.append(productNo +"\t"
                            + quantity + "\t" 
                            + "$" + lineAmount5 +"\t"
                            + "$" + orderAmount);

                    break;

            }
```

Comment: "I need to keep track of all the value of calculation for each case and then need to add it up" - I'm afraid this isn't at all clear...

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Sounds like you should save the results in a list and sum them up afterwards.

Comment: yeah, I need to save the results, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using switch-case you can do the same in a loop as you are not doing anything different in the cases -

```
int lineAmount = 0;
int orderAmount = 0;
for (int product : products) {
lineAmount = quantity * product;
orderAmount += lineAmount;
textarea.append(productNo +"\t"
                        + quantity + "\t" 
                        + "$" + lineAmount +"\t"
                        + "$" + orderAmount + "\n" );
}
```

This code is based on the assumption that you have a list of products within which you were calling switch case... That entire code can be replaced with this...
If you need to associate a particular product with a particular number, then you could use Enum and use that here instead inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what you are looking for, but I'll take a guess. If you're trying to get a line total for each of five items, as well as a sum total, you could use an array for the line totals, defined somewhere before your switch statement:

```
double[] lineTotals = new double[5];
double orderTotal = 0;
```

Then you can put the values for each item in the array, remembering that indexes start at 0 instead of 1:

```
switch(productNo) {
    case 1:
        lineAmounts[0] = quantity * products[0];
        orderAmount = +lineAmounts[0];
        textArea.append(productNo +"\t"
            + quantity + "\t" 
            + "$" + lineAmount1 +"\t"
            + "$" + orderAmount + "\n" );
        break;

    case 2: ... etc ...
}
```